# write to file with subprocess popen

Tags: subprocess, adb, logcat, popen

I am writing to file as below

```
subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'logcat', '>', 'log.txt'])
```

But rather than writing to file it writes to console. I guess it is reading first 2 commands only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that redirection with '>' works with subprocess. However, you can define where output goes by specifying it in 'stderr' like so:

```
f = open('log.txt', 'w')
p = subprocess.Popen(['abd', 'logcat'], stdout=f)
```

Hope this helps.